# Can you still use the website setup for Crystal reports in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

So I'm trying to use the website set up option for Crystal reports in Visual Studio 2022 but I can't get it to work. The SAP website instructions want me to make a new website by going to
File -> New Web Site
but that's not an option in VS2022. I've tried making a new project from all of the ASP.NET C# options but when adding the Crystal Reports tools I get a "The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in active designer" prompt. I've successfully set up Crystal Reports using a Windows Form Application so my version/ install aren't the problem. Am I using the wrong project type or does crystal reports just not support the website option in Visual Studio 2022?

Just in case it helps: Crystal reports Version: CRforVS6413SP35_0-80007712
Visual Studio Version: Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.6